# Duvidas com node.js - Error: route.js:162

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou enfrentando problemas ao executar minha aplicação.
Realizei os mapeamentos certinho, conforme o livro no qual estou aprendendo (MEAN stack da Casa do Código).

Arquivo express.js

```
// config/express.js
var express = require('express');
var home = require('../app/routes/home');

module.exports = function () {

    //Utilizando o Express
    var app = express();

    //Variaveis de Ambiente
    app.set('port', 3000);

    //Middlewares
    app.use(express.static('./public'));

    //Template Engines
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', './app/views');

    //Rotas
    home(app);

    //Retornando a aplicação
    return app;
};
```

Arquivo route (home.js)

```
// app/routes/home.js
var controller = require('../controllers/home');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/index', controller.index);
    app.get('/', controller.index);   
}
```

Arquivo controller (home.js)

```
// app/controllers/home.js

module.exports = function () {
    var controller = {};

    controller.index = function (req, res) {
        // Retorna a página index.ejs
        res.render('index', {nome: 'Express'});
    };

    return controller;
}
```

Por via das dúvidas coloco aqui também o arquivo server.js

```
// server.js
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./config/express')();

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express Server escutando na porta ' + app.get('port'));    
});
```

E por fim, erro apresentado:

```
C:\Sandbox\contatooh>node server.js
C:\Sandbox\contatooh\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:162
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at C:\Sandbox\contatooh\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:162:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Sandbox\contatooh\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:158:15)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Sandbox\contatooh\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:421:19)
    at module.exports (C:\Sandbox\contatooh\app\routes\home.js:5:9)
    at module.exports (C:\Sandbox\contatooh\config\express.js:21:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Sandbox\contatooh\server.js:3:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás a defenir mal o módulo controler. Repara que tens uma função:

```
var x = function () {
    var controller = {};
    controller.index = 'bar';
    return controller;
}
```

e estás a tentar aceder diretamente `controller.index` de fora da função. Tens duas soluções, ou usas `x().index` e neste caso invocas a função para ela poder fazer `return` e devolver-te o objeto `controler`; ou então exportas o objeto `controler` diretamente. Eu usaria a segunda opção e nesse caso o teu código ficaria assim:

```
// app/controllers/home.js
var controller = {};
controller.index = function (req, res) {
    // Retorna a página index.ejs
    res.render('index', {nome: 'Express'});
};
module.exports = controller;
```

Comment: Consegui dessa forma, obrigado cara!

Comment: @LucasMonteiroInácio ótimo! Fico contente de poder ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta passar o controller pra dentro do exports:

```
var controller = require('../controllers/home');
```

Comment: Tentei porém sem sucesso, infelizmente.

Comment: Esse erro dá quando vc tá tentando usar um objeto que ainda não foi definido. Confere se o caminho dos teus requires realmente chegam nos modules